# Query to get the most recent date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following data that I am trying to pull the record with the most recent incident date. However I am unable to get the query to work correctly using first,last, max, or min.

Here is an example of the data. I am looking to pull the most recent date from.  It should also be noted that if a particular ID has no incidents I still need the ID to show in the result.

```
`ID     FirstName LastName srp_ID Incident Date Preventability mpp_senioritydate
xxxxxx  James     Naismith                                    5/16/2010                                 
xxxxxx  John      Smith                                       7/22/2006                 
xxxxxx  John      Smith    2396                               7/22/2006                
xxxxxx  John      Smith    2240                               7/22/2006
xxxxxx  John      Smith    1140   2/15/2010 10:00:00    TP    7/22/2006
xxxxxx  John      Smith    1206   5/19/2010 07:40:00    NTP   7/22/2006`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE [Incident Date] = (
    SELECT Max([Incident Date]) FROM MyTable 
    WHERE NOT IsNull([Incident Date] )
)
```

**EDIT**

It sounds like you might want something more like this:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Max([Incident Date])
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, FirstName, LastName
```

This will give you what you've asked for.  If I'm misunderstanding and you need the *entire* record, then you need to create a pointer.

Basically, a "pointer" dataset is a query that contains some unique Key value.  Once you get the pointer dataset, you can link back to your original table and pull the records that match your Key value.  So, if your dataset looks something like this:

```
Key   ID     FirstName LastName srp_ID Incident Date Preventability mpp_senioritydate
1   xxxxxx   James     Naismith                                     5/16/2010
2   xxxxxx   John      Smith                                        7/22/2006 
3   xxxxxx   John      Smith    2396                                7/22/2006 
4   xxxxxx   John      Smith    2240                                7/22/2006 
5   xxxxxx   John      Smith    1140   2/15/2010 10:00:00    TP     7/22/2006    
6   xxxxxx   John      Smith    1206   5/19/2010 07:40:00    NTP    7/22/2006
```

Then you need to get a query result that will give you Keys = 1 & 6.  So, you could do something like:

```
SELECT
  MAX(Keys)
FROM
  MyTable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Max([Incident Date]) AS MaxDate
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY MyTable.ID) mx
  ON MyTable.ID = mx.ID AND (MyTable.[Incident Date]=mx.MaxDate or MaxDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY
  MyTable.ID
```

You now have your relevant keys.  So, you could use this as a pointer to pull all the data from your first table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Keys IN (SELECT Keys FROM MyQuery)
```

There's probably a way to integrate the two together, but unfortunately my brain is a little cooked from a long week.  But hopefully that gives you a push in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is also only returning 1 result as well.

Comment: Just re-reading and that second part is confusing.  My answer will only pull one specific row; the row with the most recent Incident date.  I don't understand the part about pulling records with no Incident dates; how can you know which is most current if there's no date to compare to?

Comment: If there is no date it still needs to pull the id just with no date. So for example the ideal result using the above info would pull the James Naismith record and the John Smith 5/19/2010 record.

Comment: So you want the max Incident Date for each person?  What if James had 4 records and none of them had an Incident Date?  Is there a secondary field to look at, or would you pull all 4 records?

Comment: Ok so essentially what I want is a list of all the Distinct First Name Last Name Combos and their most recent incident date so if the James had 4 records and no incident dates it would return 1 result for a James Naismith with no Incident date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT mytable.*
FROM
  mytable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      mytable.FirstName,
      mytable.LastName,
      Max(mytable.IncidentDate) AS MaxIncidentDate
    FROM
      mytable
    GROUP BY
      mytable.FirstName,
      mytable.LastName) mx
  ON
    mytable.FirstName = mx.FirstName
    AND mytable.LastName = mx.LastName
    AND (mytable.IncidentDate=mx.MaxIncidentDate
         OR mx.MaxIncidentDate IS NULL)
```

The subquery will return all FirstName,LastName combos with the maximum incident date (or null if there's no incident date). Then you can join this subquery back to the original table where FirstName and LastName matches, and the date is the maximum one or there's no maximum.